# Hangfire Error Duplicate (1406-CurrentCulture)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm doing this call

```
client.Schedule<IJob<T>>(job => job.Execute(arg, null), delay)
```

And getting this error.

```
hangfire Duplicate entry '1406-CurrentCulture' for key 'IX_JobParameter_JobId_Name'
```

I'm not completely sure why I get this. suddenly I got this error all the time.

My database is a MySQL Db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the naming of my Hangfire DB to be the problem. Adding `TablesPrefix = "Hangfire",` to the config of Hangifre helped me. Before I had little h in hangfire. Dont know if anyone else had this problem but this fixed my issue.